# I want to execute loop depending on the Json Extractor & In loop i want to add another json extractor in Json Expression according to loop iteration

Tags: foreach, jmeter, json-extract

I have added one sampler & get the response of it.
In Response there is Big Json array, like There are multiple AppObjects array & In one AppObjects array there are multiple DSQ array. Now i used Json Extractor to get all the AppObjects.
Here is the Screenshot

[AppObject Json Extractor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQnC9.png)

Then i want to extract AppObject wise Dsqs so i used Json extractor. But its only for one AppObject id whose Id is 0.
I have used 0 as a static layout but gradually it should increase with 0,1,2 & etc.

[DSQs json Extractor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGSnw.png)

Pls give me steps too get AppObject wise DSQs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of current `appObjectIDs` inside the ForEach Controller you can use [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) in combination with `__jm__ForEach Controller__idx` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

```
${__V(appObjectIDs_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)